# How to change position (x,y coordinate) of a view dynamically

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have an application which loads a view in it. I want to position the loaded view in 450pt of y cordinate. How to do that.

Regards
Ranjan

Comment: Please mark my answer as the correct one :) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) and in particular the properties `frame`, `bounds` and `center`

I assume that you are adding a subview so you want it in the coordinate that is relative to the parent view. Then you use frame.

```
CGRect r = [subView frame];
r.origin.y = 450.0f;
[subView setFrame:r];
```

Something like that.

Comment: Thanks. Can u pls give an example?


Regards

Comment: Thanks. its done. I had to make a little change.


CGRect r = [subView.view frame];
r.origin.y = 450.0f;
[subView.view setFrame:r];


Regards

Comment: Please mark my answer as the correct one :) Glad I could help!